# OTP/ Flash chip copy

Tags: microcontroller

I want to make copies of some OTP chips but never worked with them. Can I get a programmer that will copy them and will the same programmers also do flash, eprom etc?

Do I have to copy OTP to OTP or can I copy a flash based chip to OTP? Can they be copy protected?  Thanks so much.

---

The chip in question is NXP    -   P87C54X2BN   A 40 pin dip Microcontroller it goes to a weather station I want to expand.

Comment: Specific chip and link to data sheet?

Comment: Some (many?) OTP PROMs are really UV-erasable, but are in a cheap plastic package rather than an expensive ceramic package with a quartz window.  They can be read by any programmer that can program the related UVPROM.

Comment: MCU OTP chips are usually read-protected after verification by the OEM. OTP memory chips cannot typically be read-protected so you can copy them to a file and thence to a new OTP or flash chip.

Comment: "I want to make copies of some OTP chips" - why?

Answer (score 1):

At its most basic, memory is just a sequence of words, and the type of memory they're encoded in doesn't really matter if it's only being read. You just read the memory contents into a binary file, and write the binary file contents onto another memory device. Assuming of course you can actually read the contents in the first place.

Having said that, it *could* be possible for the memory contents to be a program that attempts to write out to the memory and refuses to run if it becomes changed, but such a thing is rare almost to the point of non-existence. It's usually more cost-effective to use any available read protection mechanism the memory device has instead.